# Undefined reference issue when calling get_uuid() method of Customer class - "Customer::get_uuid"

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I currently have the following issue when I am trying to compile my program using CMake. After reading about this on the internet for a bit, I noticed most people have this issue because they add a function to a header file, and then do not define it in the implementation file, however, it seems my problem is not the same.

**Error**

```
libdatamanager.a(datamanager.cpp.obj):datamanager.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `Customer::get_uuid[abi:cxx11]()'        
libdatamanager.a(datamanager.cpp.obj):datamanager.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `Customer::get_uuid[abi:cxx11]()'       
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\mtm-app.dir\build.make:106: recipe for target 'mtm-app.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [mtm-app.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:261: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mtm-app.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mtm-app.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:134: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Customer.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "customerdata.h"

#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H

class Customer
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string uuid;
    CustomerData* customerData;
public:
    Customer( std::string uuid, std::string name, CustomerData* CustomerData );

    Customer( std::string name, CustomerData* CustomerData );

    std::string get_name();

    std::string get_uuid();

    CustomerData* get_customer_data();
};

#endif
```

**Customer.cpp**

```
#include "customer.h"
#include "customerdata.h"
#include "../util.cpp"
#include <iostream>

Customer::Customer( std::string uuid, std::string name, CustomerData* customerData )
{
    this->name = name;
    this->uuid = uuid;
    this->customerData = customerData;
}

Customer::Customer( std::string name, CustomerData* customerData )
{
    this->name = name;
    this->uuid = uuid::generate_uuid();
    this->customerData = customerData;
}

std::string Customer::get_name()
{
    return this->name;
}

std::string Customer::get_uuid()
{
    return this->uuid;
}

CustomerData* Customer::get_customer_data()
{
    return this->customerData;
}
```

**DataManager.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "../container/customer.h"

#ifndef DATAMANAGER_H
#define DATAMANAGER_H

class DataManager
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Customer*> customers = {};
public:
    DataManager();

    void add_customer( Customer* Customer );

    void remove_customer( Customer* customer );

    std::unordered_map<std::string, Customer*> get_customers();
};

#endif
```

**DataManager.cpp**

```
#include "datamanager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "../container/customer.h"

DataManager::DataManager()
{
    
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, Customer*> DataManager::get_customers()
{
    return this->customers;
}

void DataManager::add_customer( Customer* customer )
{
    this->customers.insert( std::make_pair( customer->get_uuid(), customer ) );
}

void DataManager::remove_customer( Customer* customer )
{
   this->customers.erase( customer->get_uuid() );
}
```

I checked whether or not I have circular dependencies, tried forward declarations, and adjusted my CMakeLists.txt file's order of libraries to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27.0)
project(MTMApp VERSION 1.0.0)

add_library(
    util
    util.cpp
)

add_library(
    insurance
    container/insurance.h
    container/insurance.cpp
)

add_library(
    customerdata
    container/customerdata.h
    container/customerdata.cpp
)

add_library(
    customer
    container/customer.h
    container/customer.cpp
)

add_library(
    datamanager
    data/datamanager.h
    data/datamanager.cpp
)

add_subdirectory(SQLiteCpp)

add_executable(mtm-app app.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mtm-app
    sqlite3
    SQLiteCpp
    util
    insurance
    customerdata
    customer
    datamanager
)
```

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags, like C.

Comment: You got the error about the symbol which is used by `datamanager` library and provided by `customerdata` one. But when create `mtm-app` you link `customerdata` library first, and only then link `datamanager` library. This case is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/24675715#24675715). CMake allows you to specify dependencies between static libraries: `target_link_libraries(datamanager customerdata)`. That way CMake will automatically provide the proper linking order.

Answer (score 0):

The shown makefile appears to link with `libcustomer.a`, first, then `datamanager.a`.

`datamanager.a` references undefined symbols which are defined in `libcustomer.a`.

Too late.

Static library linking is generally not recursive. A static library with undefined symbols that are defined in a second static library must be linked first, then followed by the second static library.

You'll need to carefully go over and work out all the dependencies of all your libraries static. You must make sure that their linking order is correct, that the libraries are listed in the order they get linked, and a static library that references symbols in other static libraries always gets linked before them.